# Using Oozie to combine output file parts

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Is it possible to use Oozie to concatenate the output of a MapReduce job into a single file?  Lets say I have the output ...

```
part-r-00000
part-r-00001
part-r-00002
```

and I just want...

```
output.csv
```

I know I can pull them down as a single file with `hadoop fs -getmerge`, but I'm curious if it's possible with a workflow application and HDFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple options i can think of:

1. Amend the job that produced this output to use a single reducer
2. Run a map-reduce action with identity mapper, identity reducer and single reducer

Comment: Yeah so far I've only seen the single reducer solution.  I was hoping for something a little cleaner.  If it turns out there's no other way, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way to concat files that doesn't involve pulling everything to one server and then uploading back up to HDFS

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use pig or Java to call

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#concat-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path:A-

or maybe add it to your own fork of Oozie's fs-action.

Alternatively, using webhdfs:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Concat_Files .

You could wrap that curl call in a shell or ssh action.